# Is there a simple website that can show the different forms of any word?

Tags: word-form

Some words for example I don't know what the adjective form of it is

But looking for it in google sometimes take time

So, I will be glad if you know a website which provides all the different forms of any word easily and quickly.

Comment: I use wordhippo.com, but sometimes it doesn't find the word :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources. You might find the [Resources thread on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/735/) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/) is a very useful dictionary that allows you to see different usages of a single word depending on the context. Though it won't show you the alternative form of the word when it's an adjective, adverb, verb by adding a prefix (or removing one), it does show when a word is x part of the speech in a sentence. Take a look at [short](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/short):

> adj. 
>   having little length or height:
>   the shortest boy in class.
>
> adv. 
>   abruptly or suddenly:
>   to stop short.
>
> n. [countable]
>   something short.
>
> v. 
>   to form a short circuit (in): [ ~ + obj]:

It shows different meanings of the word depending on the context, however, it won't show that *shortly* is simply the adjective *short + -ly*. Then again *short (adv.) =/= shortly (adv.)*

Comment: helpful but doesn't fulfill what i want .. like the word rely : rely.. reliable .. reliance ..reliant and so on

Comment: Well, there's also the fact that if you take a look at one of the traditional dictionaries you'll get what you want in some words. http://books.google.com.co/books?id=qYHPuEwaBswC&pg=PA786&lpg=PA786&dq=rely+reliable+reliance+reliant&source=bl&ots=McBQKAvMDx&sig=5ZM0Jk2iE7hhmD5Z6hPQ1LtjWjI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IJNaVJ3aF4qpgwTI-YO4DA&ved=0CDgQ6AEwBjgK#v=onepage&q=rely%20reliable%20reliance%20reliant&f=false

Comment: @Maher Those are separate words, not forms of *rely*.  They contain derivational affixes, not inflectional affixes.